# Specify encoding/compression for many variables in xarray dataset when write to_netcdf

Tags: python-xarray

I have been writing out some xarray.Datasets that have multiple variables. Currently, in order to keep the size manageable I specify the encoding, e.g. zlib, but needs to be applied on a variable (dataArray) by variable basis.

What is the good way to apply the same encoding argument to all variables? e.g.

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 1440, lon: 2880)
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 -90.0 -89.88 -89.75 -89.62 -89.5 -89.38 -89.25 ...
  * lon      (lon) float64 -180.0 -179.9 -179.8 -179.6 -179.5 -179.4 -179.2 ...
Data variables:
a1     (lat, lon) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan 0.0 ...
b     (lat, lon) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
c     (lat, lon) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan 0.0 ...
d      (lat, lon) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan 0.0 ...
e      (lat, lon) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan 0.0 ...
```

when writing out this dataset, we would use:

```
ds.to_netcdf(filename, encoding={'a1':{'zlib': True,'complevel': 5},'b':{'zlib': True,'complevel': 5},'c':{'zlib': True,'complevel': 5},'d':{'zlib': True,'complevel': 5},'e':{'zlib': True,'complevel': 5}})
```

For more variables this gets very long winded. One option would be to write each dataarray to the netcdf in a sequential append basis, but this also seems convoluted when the dataset is ready to go.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'd just create the encoding parameter dynamically:

```
comp = dict(zlib=True, complevel=5)
encoding = {var: comp for var in ds.data_vars}
ds.to_netcdf(filename, encoding=encoding)
```

Comment: Thanks - that's an elegant solution!

Comment: I tried this solution and it produced a ValueError: unexpected encoding for scipy backend: ['zlib', 'complevel']. Solved by installing netcdf4 (pip install netcdf4) and specifying the engine='netcdf4'. Just in case anyone else has the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can store the encoding info for each variable within the Dataset:

```
comp = dict(zlib=True, complevel=5)
for var in ds.data_vars: 
    var.encoding.update(comp)
ds.to_netcdf(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

The chosen solution overwrites all encoding. Probably, the dataset is opened with `xr.open_mfdataset()`. This takes the encoding from the first file. What I have seen with ERA5 data is that the `scale_factor` is not applicable to other ERA5 files when writing to a file with int dtype (which is the dtype of ERA5 datasets). The solution is to remove the `dtype` attribute (removing `scale_factor` also seems to work, but reduces accuracy). If you overwrite the encoding with `dict(zlib=True, complevel=5)`, the `dtype` and `scale_factor` attribute are both gone, so it solves the issue but not because of the right reason.

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/pydata/xarray/discussions/5709

This answer caused `_FillValue` to go missing`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40818232

This answer raised 'RuntimeError: NetCDF: Invalid argument':  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66333685

But, this worked:

```py
encoding = {}
encoding_keys = ("_FillValue", "dtype", "scale_factor", "add_offset", "grid_mapping")
for data_var in ds.data_vars:
    encoding[data_var] = {key: value for key, value in ds[data_var].encoding.items() if key in encoding_keys}
    encoding[data_var].update(zlib=True, complevel=5)

ds.to_netcdf(filename, encoding=encoding)
```